# 404 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI after oauth2 successful authorization

Tags: spring, rest, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have problem with Spring REST oAuth2 configuration. Springs sees and map my URLs, but after oauth2 security check (successful) claims there is no URL to match. But I have no idea why, because Spring sees it on app initialisation.
I am able to properly authenticate with /oauth/token and generate token.
I am just unable to process requests which do not need authorization with token.

Spring 4.0.6, spring-security 3.2.4, Spring-security-oauth2 2.0.1

Logs from context initialisation

```
2014-08-29 08:56:26.415 [Scanner-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/users/{email}],methods=[PUT],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.concurrent.Callable<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> com.example.user.UserCommandsController.update(java.lang.String)
2014-08-29 08:56:26.416 [Scanner-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/users/{email}],methods=[DELETE],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.concurrent.Callable<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> com.example.user.UserCommandsController.delete(java.lang.String)
2014-08-29 08:56:26.416 [Scanner-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/users/logout],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.concurrent.Callable<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> com.example.user.UserCommandsController.logout()
2014-08-29 08:56:26.416 [Scanner-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/api/users],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.concurrent.Callable<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void>> com.example.user.UserCommandsController.signup(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

After sending request

```
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users'; against '/api/users'
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/users; Attributes: [permitAll]
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.a.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@31b7d21c, returned: 1
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2014-08-29 09:00:58.654 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2014-08-29 09:00:58.655 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.w.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/api/users]
2014-08-29 09:00:58.655 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/users
2014-08-29 09:00:58.655 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/api/users]
2014-08-29 09:00:58.655 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/users
2014-08-29 09:00:58.655 [qtp1157726741-28] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/api/users]
2014-08-29 09:00:58.655 [qtp1157726741-28] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/users] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

And configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("sample-resource-id");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/buildings/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/api/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/buildings/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
    }
}



@Controller
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("default")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
     * By default all request need authentication. Only those which do not need it, shall be specified explicitly.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/buildings/**").permitAll()//to consider anonymous()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users").permitAll()//to consider anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/app/**","/webjars/**", "/images/**", "/oauth/uncache_approvals", "/oauth/cache_approvals");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "authenticationManagerBean")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Part of user controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserCommandsController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private AccountRecoveryMailer accountRecoveryMailer;
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Inject
    public UserCommandsController(final UserService userService, final AccountRecoveryMailer accountRecoveryMailer,
        final MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.accountRecoveryMailer = accountRecoveryMailer;
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Callable<ResponseEntity<Void>> signup(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password) {
        return () -> {
            //do something
           };
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to secure all requests and only some of them make with free access (or maybe with only Authorization header to match client_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution for my problem. The root of this evil thing was beans initialisation, or better to say their scopes. BTW SSL isn't needed.

**Wrong configuration below, do not blindly copy-paste.**

I had two @*ComponentScan* classes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class,
    excludeFilters = @Filter({RestController.class, Controller.class, Service.class, Repository.class, Configuration.class}))
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    //some code
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
class ApplicationConfig {
    //some code
}
```

And mine WebAppInitialization code

```
@Order(2)
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ApplicationConfig.class, DataSourceConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
        registration.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "default");
    }
}
```

As you can see, entire components class path scanning with all type of beans would be initialized in *getRootConfigClasses()* method, and only part of beans would be initialized in *getServletConfigClasses()* method, due to *WebMvcConfig.class* and its exclusion of some bean types in component scanning. This *shall be enough* in my opinion for Spring, because beans from *rootContext* are available for *servletContext*. And was, but only for web app instantiation. Spring Security oAuth2 haven't seen controller mappings.

**Solution** to this problem was to get rid of component scanning in WebMvcConfig, and change  *getServletConfigClasses()* method to this:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
   return new Class<?>[]{ApplicationConfig.class, WebMvcConfig.class};
}
```

Thanks to eager caching of Spring beans, everything shall be fine.

Answer (score -1):

You setup the server with oAuth2, that server can be accessed in secure fashion (https:) only.
If you need to provide non-secure(http:) service, you have to create another server.

Let consider that if your home's door has lock, and only the persons who have the key can enter your home, your home is secure.

If you add another door without lock to your home, your home becomes not-secure.

If you want to make door without lock, you should install that door to other hut for non-secure use.

Secure home, and non-secure hut.
These may be what you want to build on your server.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. This makes obvious sense, but this still doesn't work.
  
`curl -k -X POST https://localhost:8443/api/users --header "Content-Type:application/json"`  
  
`<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/users. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
</body>`